Failover cluster - which process is role controlling?
I am using windows server 2022 standard. I have created failover cluster, with several roles, each role is controlling one windows service. Now I would like to check which service exactly is controlled by which role (basically the service that I've picked for each role), but I don't know how to do it. I've tried to check properties on each role, but this information is not shown.


